# Comparing elements in two numpy arrays results in a memory address

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I'm comparing the individual elements in two numpy arrays.  The array elements are integers. I'm using the 'equal_arrays' function to do the comparision but it results in giving me the memory address of the result object:

Here is the code:

```
    act = actual_direction
    pre = predicted_direction
    np.sum(act == pre)
    comparison = act == pre
    equal_arrays = comparison.all
    print(f'equal_arrays : {equal_arrays}\n')
```

result:

```
   equal_arrays : <built-in method all of numpy.ndarray object at 0x00000122CA6CA3F0>
```

Do I have to access the memory address to get the results or is there a more elegant way to get the answer?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `equal_arrays = comparison.all()`

Comment: Thanks Quang.  I forgot the parenthesis.  That answer gives one result, True or False for the entire array.  What I am trying to do is get a comparison  for each individual element of the arrays.

Comment: The `comparison` array is a boolean array with True or False for each item in the array

Answer (score 2):

Based on what i understand, you need a way to get an array with True or False values, for each corresponding element from the two matrixes, given they have the same shape? (What I am trying to do is get a comparison for each individual element of the arrays.)

If so you can try something to this:

```
a = np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]])
b = np.array([[3,2,1], [6,5,4], [9,8,7]])
print(a == b)
```

Output:

```
[[False  True False]
 [False  True False]
 [False  True False]]
```

Comment: Thanks @DeltaHaxor. I will ask the question another way because what I really want is a count of each individual item and they include negative values.  Thanks all!